# Why I receive an infinite loop for this code?

Tags: javascript

I am using [mediaelement player](http://mediaelementjs.com/) and I want to dynamically set current time (from where the song to start from).

If I do it like this it works perfectly:

```
mediaElement.setCurrentTime(22);
```

(so the song will start from second 22th).

If I want to dynamically set the start from, like:

```
var cur_time = new Date().getTime();
var songToStartFrom = (cur_time - song.startTime) / (1000);
mediaElement.setCurrentTime(songToStartFrom );
```

its going into an infinite loop. (I am very sure that songToStartFrom is fine in seconds)

I simply don't understand why it works for static values but for dynamic not?

**UPDATE**: entire code here

```
player = new MediaElementPlayer('#ui_audio', {
      features: ['playpause'],
      audioWidth: 30,
      audioHeight: 30,
      success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
        // Player is ready
        mediaElement.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
          var cur_time = new Date().getTime();
          console.log("--current time: " + cur_time);
          console.log("--song time: " + song.startTime);
          console.log("--media elem time: " + (cur_time - song.startTime) / (1000));
          var songToStartFrom = (cur_time - song.startTime) / (1000);
          console.log("DURATION: " + mediaElement.duration);
          mediaElement.setCurrentTime(22);
          mediaElement.play();
        }, false);
        mediaElement.addEventListener('playing', function () {

          //pushListenerInfo();
        });
        mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function () {
          //removeListenerInfo();
        });
        mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function () {
          //removeListenerInfo();
        });
      }
    });
```

Example of infinite output:

```
listen-moment.js:31 --current time: 1428777176774
listen-moment.js:32 --song time: 1428777166000
listen-moment.js:33 --media elem time: 10.774
listen-moment.js:35 DURATION: 29.875625
listen-moment.js:31 --current time: 1428777176779
listen-moment.js:32 --song time: 1428777166000
listen-moment.js:33 --media elem time: 10.779
listen-moment.js:35 DURATION: 29.875625
listen-moment.js:31 --current time: 1428777176784
listen-moment.js:32 --song time: 1428777166000
listen-moment.js:33 --media elem time: 10.784
listen-moment.js:35 DURATION: 29.875625
listen-moment.js:31 --current time: 1428777176788
listen-moment.js:32 --song time: 1428777166000
listen-moment.js:33 --media elem time: 10.788
listen-moment.js:35 DURATION: 29.875625
listen-moment.js:31 --current time: 1428777176795
listen-moment.js:32 --song time: 1428777166000
listen-moment.js:33 --media elem time: 10.795
```

Example of finite output (and player starts playing fine):

```
--current time: 1428777382847
listen-moment.js:32 --song time: 1428777376000
listen-moment.js:33 --media elem time: 6.847
listen-moment.js:35 DURATION: 29.875625
```

Comment: Where's the loop? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @IlyaKogan These 4 console lines are printed infinitely if I replace 22 with songToStartFrom.

Comment: What does `console.log(song.startTime);` shows????

Comment: Where do you initialize song.startTime? I don't see that in your code

Comment: @EvanBechtol coming from outside; I was just proving with the logs that its fine..

Comment: Looks like either `.setCurrentTime()` or `.play()` fire a `canplay` event?

Comment: @Bergi I was thinking that too, but then why with a hardcoded value (eg: 22) its not goint into infinite loop?

Comment: Is mediaElement.setCurrentTime (); expecting an integer form instead of a decimal?

Comment: @EvanBechtol No, it works fine with `22.000` too..

Comment: Can you please log the values of `songToStartFrom`, too?

Comment: @Bergi yes, eg: ```songToStartFrom: 17.715```

Comment: I think the issue is this: calling `setCurrentTime` will fire a `canplay` event. In the case of a static value, it won't trigger the event again because the value is the same. But when you calculate the value, it is different each time because it uses the currentTime so it will keep triggering the event.

Comment: @CristianBoariu: so it might fire an event if the value is smaller than the current time (and the media is already loaded), but not fire the event if the to-be-set value is in the future?

Comment: @Vic grr, it makes sens, so somewhere under the hook the player retaing the value I set and compare it all the time with the new value.... You are right!

Answer (score 0):

Correct code to be helpful for others (notice I've moved the sensitive code from `canplay` event to `playing` event.

```
function startPlaying(song) {

    console.log("--will play: " + song.name);

    var tag = '<audio id="ui_audio" src="' + song.location + '" type="audio/mp3"></audio>';
    $('#ui_audio_wrapper').html(tag);

    var curTime = new Date().getTime();
    var songToStartFrom = (curTime - song.startTime) / (1000);

    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#ui_audio', {
      features: ['playpause'],
      audioWidth: 30,
      audioHeight: 30,
      success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
        // Player is ready
        mediaElement.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
          mediaElement.play();
        }, false);
        mediaElement.addEventListener('playing', function () {
          console.log("--current time: " + curTime);
          console.log("--song time: " + song.startTime);
          console.log("--media elem time: " + (curTime - song.startTime) / (1000));
          console.log("DURATION: " + mediaElement.duration);
          console.log("--songToStartFrom: " + songToStartFrom);
          if (songToStartFrom < mediaElement.duration) {
            mediaElement.setCurrentTime(songToStartFrom);
          }
          pushListenerInfo();
        });
        mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function () {
          console.log("--setting current time triggered");
          removeListenerInfo();
        });
        mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function () {
          removeListenerInfo();
        });
      }
    });

  }
```